# Centering group of dynamically growing labels vertically using auto layout in interface builder

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

I am having a view, which will have always a constant height. Inside this view there are three labels, the top label can grow up-to two lines and rest are fixed to one line.

Leading and trailing edges of all labels are fixed to superview, but height of all labels is being calculated intrinsically.

[image]

I want to center all the three labels vertically for both the cases where top label is having one line and where top label is having two lines.

I want to do it using auto-layout in Xcode interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this only by adding another UIView in the view hierarchy. So this goes like

```
UIView
  -> SubView
      -> lbl1
      -> lbl2
      -> lbl3
```

Now coming to constraint, apply these

**SubView to UIView:-** CenterX, CenterY, Leading = 0, Trailing = 0, Height >= 67; Vertical Compression Resistance = 751;
**lbl1 to subview:-** Leading = 0, Trailing = 0, Top = 0, Bottom to Lbl2 = 2, Height >= 21; Vertical Compression Resistance = 751;
**lbl2 to subview:-** Leading = 0, Trailing = 0,Top to lbl1 = 2, Bottom to lbl3 = 2, Height = 21;
**lbl3 to subview:-** Leading = 0, Trailing = 0,Top to lbl2 = 2,Bottom = 0, Height = 21;

For `Subview` i have calculated height based on each label height as 21 and spacing between each as 2. `So SubView.Height = 21*3+2+2 = 67`. If you choose a different value then modify the constraints value accordingly.

Comment: I was missing lbl3 to subview: Bottom=0 constraint because of that SubView to UIView: Height >=67 was producing Inequality Constraint Ambiguity error in interface builder. As soon as I put that constraint it started working like a charm. I did not modify Vertical Compression Resistance for any element and did not put any height constraint on any label as height was being calculated by auto layout system intrinsically for the labels. Thanks.

Comment: @devgr You are welcome and i appreciate your approach about achieving it without compression resistance. I went with approach i thought would work and will definitely check myself by removing the resistance property.